# fatal: unable to access ".....": gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

Tags: git, github, gitlab, handshake

I've been using Git for the past few months. Recently when I try to clone or to push, I keep on getting this error. I've researched on the internet but so far no solution has worked for me. Does anyone have an idea?

External note : Now I moved to different country, it was working perfectly where I was before.
Git Version : 2.11.0   , OS : Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)

Error :

```
git push
fatal: unable to access 'https://**************/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
```

Comment: Are you in a country which blocks encrypted connections?  Because it looks like that's what's happening.

Comment: @bk2204 - Currently I am in India. So if it is because of this, what is the solution ?

Comment: This could also be a TLS incompatibility issue.  Can you edit your question to indicate the OS you're using and your version of Git?

Comment: @bk2204 - Is it a good idea to reinstall git ? Will I get the same issue after reinstalling ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error means that Git cannot establish a secure connection to the server you're trying to use.  Your version of Git uses the GnuTLS library to set up TLS (encrypted) connections, and for some reason that setup process is failing.

This could be for a couple of reasons.  One is that your server (which one you haven't mentioned) is using an incompatible set of cipher suites or TLS versions, and there's no encryption algorithms in common that can be chosen.  It's also possible that you have someone tampering with the connection via a MITM device.

The version of Git and GnuTLS you're using should work just fine with most standard servers.  Re-installing it won't help.  You can try upgrading to a newer version of Debian, or you can try building Git yourself against a version of libcurl using OpenSSL.  You can also just switch to SSH-based remotes, which will avoid this incompatibility altogether.

Comment: There's an opensource project that helps with that - https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/git-openssl-shellscript . It saved me a lot of time when bitbucket decided to suddenly remove ciphers, and broke my git on an old Debian box.

Comment: Running shellscipt give me nightmare. Switching to SSH remote is better.

Answer (score 47):

This is solution fix this issue on ubuntu server 14.04.x

1, Edit file:

```
sudo nano  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

2, Add to file sources.list

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe
```

3, Run command update and update CURL to new version

```
apt-get update && apt-get install curl
```

4, Check version (Optional):

```
curl -V
Response :

curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

5, Test connect with bitbucket (Optional)

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git ls-remote https://bitbucket.org/
Response:


* Closing connection 0
fatal: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/' not found
```

This done.

Comment: The best answer!  Question is about repair git http pull/push - not how to use SSH-keys.

Comment: Had the same issue as the author. This fixed it for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Doesn't work so great on a full desktop system, where upgrading curl from a newer version leads to uninstalling lots of dependent packages and breaking others. Also, if the trick does work for you, remove the edit to the apt sources ASAP after installing the new curl version, and DO NOT DO an `apt-get upgrade` or equivalent before!

Answer (score 31):

I also incurred this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Quickest solution is to use ssh instead of https.
Following are steps to replace https from ssh:

1. Generate [ssh key using ssh-keygen](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html) on the server.
2. Copy public key from generated id_rsa.pub file from step 1 and add it at following links depending on repository host -

   Bitbucket - https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/ssh-keys/

   Github - https://github.com/settings/ssh/new

   Gitlab - https://gitlab.com/profile/keys
3. Now run following command to test authentication from server command line terminal

   Bitbucket

   ```
   ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
   ```

   Github

   ```
   ssh -T git@github.com
   ```

   Gitlab

   ```
   ssh -T git@gitlab.com
   ```
4. Go to repo directory and open .git/config file using emac or vi
5. Replace remote "origin" url (which starts with https) with following -

   For Bitbucket  -  git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo>.git

   For Github  -  git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git

   For Gitlab - git@gitlab.com:<username>/<repo>.git

Comment: This was the easiest solution by far. Really well written answer.

Comment: this worked for me but I had to have ssh://git@bitbucket.org.......

Comment: I just gave this command 'ssh -T git@gitlab.com' and gave yes to connection prompt. It got added and connection started establishing

Answer (score 3):

It might be only a part of the problem.
How about other https sites?
How are you connected to the internet?
Is your git counterpart is reachable through VPN?

Why am I asking? I faced the same problem:
Git is used in Ubuntu 22.04 VM hosted in Windows 10 Hyper-X. VM is connected to the Internet trough Default Switch (NAT) and shares OpenConnect VPN connection of the host.

One day **git** failed to fetch from remote repo that was located in private network that is reachable through VPN. Symptoms were like yours:

> gnutls_handshake() failed

After some investigation I found next facts:

1. All https resources that were reachable through VPN were ping-able with default presets from guest, but Https connection to them **could not** be established
2. Other https resources that were not under VPN were reachable and were working normally
3. While connection attempts to https resources with firefox browser I found some bad packets report in OpenConnect-GUI VPN Client Log:
   [OpenConnect Log window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOekv.png)

After that I tried to trace path to remote git repo:
[tracepath-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yEeW.png)

```bash
developer@Ubuntu-VM:~$ tracepath **.**.167.240 -n
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  172.18.224.1                                          0.485ms 
 1:  172.18.224.1                                          0.386ms 
 2:  172.18.224.1                                          0.227ms pmtu 1290
 2:  **.**.254.9                                          38.242ms 
 3:  **.**.30.14                                          32.438ms 
 4:  **.**.167.240                                        32.136ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1290 hops 4 back 4
```

Where I've noticed some **pmtu** strings in the right side of the screen and a final **Resume** note.

So, I decided to check MTU preset for my network interface:
[ifconfig-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji6ft.png)

```bash
developer@Ubuntu-VM:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.227.200  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.18.239.255
        inet6 fe80::d1b:9e02:3919:d75b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:19:76:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 56234  bytes 311928403 (311.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13927  bytes 1148583 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

as you can see, interface eth0 had **MTU 1500** (... that was too much for current VPN tunnel).

When I've changed eth0 MTU to 1290, as suggested *tracepath* utility:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1290
```

my problem was solved. (MTU has to be also changed in Ubuntu network setup settings page to take permanent effect)

Profit!

Read also: [Windows WSL: Git and gnutls_handshake() failed](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5346#issuecomment-1016469312)

Comment: This worked for me, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that it could be unrelated specifically to source code checkout with Git.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error.

You could try to compile git with OpenSSL instead of gnutls using [Paul N. Baker's shell script](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/git-openssl-shellscript/blob/master/compile-git-with-openssl.sh).

1. Create `file.sh`
2. Put the code of the link into this file
3. Give permission to this file: `chmod a+x file.sh`
4. Run: `sudo ./file.sh`

This shell script works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 as mine, using personal computer (with no proxy configured), then just update your `gnutls-bin` to the latest version

```
sudo apt-get install gnutls-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it by

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

even though I try

```
git config --global --get https.proxy
git config --global --get http.proxy
```

don't show any results, but unset https.proxy still work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this error pops out when you `pip install -r requirements.txt` and there is a GitHub link like `git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers` in it.
Just insert `mirror.ghproxy.com/` into it and it is gonna belike `git+https://mirror.ghproxy.com/github.com/huggingface/transformers`

Then pip install it again. It works for me.

BTW, maybe because I'm in China.

Comment: If u find git config too complicated or can't be authorized, this is a quick surrogate way.