# gnutls_handshake() failed (The TLS connection was non-properly terminated) while getting Fuchsia?

Tags: git, gnutls, fuchsia

I was trying to get the Google Fuchsia source code, but I keep running into a bunch of these errors:

```
ERROR: 'git fetch -p origin' failed:
stdout:
stderr:
fatal: unable to access 'https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/github.com/google/cppdap/':
gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
command fail error: exit status 128
```

As a result, the download never fully finishes, and I have an incomplete clone of the Fuchsia repo.

I know that my Git installation is fine because I can access GitHub repos over https just fine (I do it regularly).

I'm on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 13):

I disable the sslVerify in Ubuntu. And try to clone git. It works.

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you still got this error , first of all I suggest to verify the current valid url from the [docs](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/get_fuchsia_source)

```
curl -s "https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/HEAD/scripts/bootstrap?format=TEXT" | base64 --decode | bash
```

Then try to force ipv4 with `--ipv4` or update `curl` as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64403608/16279195)

```
apt-get update
```

```
apt-get install curl
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the incorrect value of https proxy variable.
The https proxy variable(`https_proxy`) was using https, where it should have used http.

```bash
# WRONG:
https_proxy=https://<proxy-url>

# CORRECT
https_proxy=http://<proxy-url>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just exit wsl2 and restart it, then solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can try

> sudo git clean -i

that solved my problem  for  error :

> git pull --tags origin main
> fatal: unable to access 'https:_git_repo_i_cant_reach _': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.